# How to display facebook Online friends in my android application?

Tags: android, facebook

I want to display my facebook online friends and offline friends suppurate.But i don't know how to display.But I am getting all my facebook friends into list in my application.

Any one please help me.....How to display online and offline friends suppurate.

Answer (score 1):

First - use the fb api. get the friends.
Second - show the list in beautiful Ui component or what ever.

So I understand that you have done the first, right?

If so, then what stops you to make some container and push back dynamically to it labels for example. After this you can try some more beautiful solution how I sad..

---

try explain more what you've done... Be more specific, please. :)

---

**EDIT 1**

Here you are: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user

Use that:
**online_presence**

> The user's Facebook Chat status. Returns a string, one of active,
>   idle, offline, or error (when Facebook can't determine presence
>   information on the server side). The query does not return the user's
>   Facebook Chat status when that information is restricted for privacy
>   reasons

**EDIT 2**

May be you need a loop all your friends and for each of them execute the query

```
   SELECT online_presence FROM user WHERE username = the_friend_from_list
```

This is a pseudocode but I'm sure you can handle it. :)

Comment: I done above two steps.and i get all friendslist in listview.But i want online friends

Comment: I've updated the answer, look there - may be it is what you need

Comment: I have a one more doubt...I want to see my friend profile and Cht with friend for that what can i do.I don"t know what exactly do...Please help me....

Comment: just read the manual. There are a methods which looks like an SQL query. There is a table with profiles, if you need some info just SELECT that column. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/profile  .. here are the methods you need. And here is an explanation of FQL (facebook query language). It's simple - excecute this query as URL. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/fql/ ... a simple GET query is sufficient fot a lot of thinks

Comment: when you SELECT the elements you need than you will receive a response with thre data. Then you just parse it and handle it - labels, html, text fields... etc - you get the idea?